# Can I use AppsScript to both copy data from one Google Sheets tab to another while appending data to certain cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’d like to make a macro for a Google Sheet using AppsScript that serves two purposes:

1. Copy data from the current tab —- the contents of columns B to E from the 7th row to the last row with data in it. Then paste that data into the first empty row in a different tab marked “Archive”.
2. For each row, if the contents of cell B is a number, append some data to it. Ex: B3 contains 12345, so turn the contents of that cell into google.com/12345.

The biggest problems I’m facing are with cell and row selection. An identical selection each time (i.e. copy-paste cells B2-D7 and append XYZ to cell B5) would be easy, but I can’t figure out how to do it with so much variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const s = "Cookie Monster"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const ash = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");//rename to archive
  const sr = 7;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 2, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 4).getValues().map(r => {
    if (!isNaN(r[0])) {
      r[0] = s + r[0];
    }
    return r;
  });
  ash.getRange(ash.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I want to exclude an item from the final output, would it be better to do so in the first or second getRange?

Comment: Try it both ways and you decide